# Null Pointer Exception in TreeMap

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, treemap

I have tried to implement a simple treemap to count the occurances of integers, but it is giving me a `NullPointerException` and I don't know how to fix it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at exercises.CountOccurances_20_07.main(CountOccurances_20_07.java:21)
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class CountOccurances_20_07 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] list = {2, 3, 40, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0};
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for(int i: list)
        {
            int key = list[i];
            if(list.length > 1)
            {
                if(map.get(key) == 0)
                {
                    map.put(key, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    int value = map.get(key).intValue(); // line 21
                    value ++;
                    map.put(key, value);
                }
            }
        }
        //get all entries into set
        Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
        //get key and value from entry set
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: entrySet)
            System.out.println(entry.getValue() + "\t" + entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case map.get(key) is returning `null` and will never be 0. Also you are using the key, to lookup up itself which doesn't sound right.

```
for(int key: list) {
    Integer count = map.get(key);
    if (count == null) count = 0;
    map.put(key, count+1);
}
```

Comment: @Doesn'tMatter I like to keep things simple. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The `NullPointerException` at line 21

```
int value = map.get(key).intValue(); // line 21
```

is due to the fact that `map.get(key)` would return null if the `key` is not present in the map.

You should use

```
if(!map.containsKey(key)){
}
```

instead of

```
if(map.get(key) == 0) {
}
```

as it evaluates to

```
if(null == 0){
}
```

and your condition is false and then the control goes to line 21.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
map.get(key) == 0
```

to

```
map.get(key) == null
```

or

```
!map.contains(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many obvious deficiencies with your code.

`Map` is constructed in place as an empty map, but is immediately queried and the `get` result unboxed:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
...
if(map.get(key) == 0)
```

`get` returns `null` for a non-existent map entry, not a zero, and unboxing will fail for a null argument.

---

Here `list` is initialized in place, but is then checked for length:

```
int[] list = {2, 3, 40, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0};
if(list.length > 1)
```

This is a redundant check, remove it.

---

```
for(int i: list)
{
  int key = list[i];
```

The way you use `int i` is very probably wrong. The *enhanced for* loop assigns each array element in turn to `i`, so what you should in all probability have is just `for (int key : list)`.

---

```
int value = map.get(key).intValue(); // line 21
```

Calling `intValue` is redundant -- auto-unboxing will take care of this. You do need to make sure that the value is not null before trying to unbox.